# Insert spaces in the string array

Tags: arrays, string, bash, whitespace

I have the following array:

```
declare -a case=("060610" "080813" "101016" "121219" "141422")
```

I want to generate another array where the elements have whitespaces inserted appropriately as:

```
"06 06 10" "08 08 13" "10 10 16" "12 12 19" "14 14 22"
```

I got till handling the elements individually using sed as:

```
echo '060610' | sed 's/../& /g'
```

But I am not being able to do it while using the array. The sed confuses the white spaces in between the elements and I am left with the output:

```
echo "${case[@]}" | sed 's/../& /g'
```

Gives me:

```
06 06 10  0 80 81 3  10 10 16  1 21 21 9  14 14 22
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Show your code that assigns to the new array.

Comment: For the output I am talking about, I used this:

echo "${case[@]}" | sed 's/../& /g'

But I am yet to know a lot about using @ for calling an element. And still getting familiar with usage of braces and quotes.

Comment: Put the code in the question.

Comment: Where did the previous answer go?

Comment: he deleted it because it didn't really work.

Comment: FYI, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You can use `printf '%s\n' "${case[@]}" | sed ...` to get each number on a separate line and avoiding the space problem

Comment: @thatotherguy  This still didn't help! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the array, not echo it as a whole, because you don't get the grouping when you echo it.

```
declare -a newcase
for c in "${case[@]}"
do
    newcase+=("$(echo "$c" | sed 's/../& /g')")
done
```

Comment: To append a new element to the array.

Comment: declare -a kpts

for c in "${case[@]}";
do kpts+=$(echo "$c" | sed 's/../&/g');
done

gives me:

060610080813101016121219141422

Am I doing alright?

Comment: You seem to be missing the space after `&`. How are you printing the array?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, you have to wrap the value in `()` to create a new array element.

Comment: I am printing it using echo "${kpts[3]}"   But now 06 06 10... resp are the 0th, 1st, 2nd element of the array. I wanted 06 06 10 as the 0th element rather. Anyway I will try to use this and see what happens.

Comment: Now it needs quotes around the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf '%s\n' "${case[@]}" | sed 's/../& /g'` to get each number on a separate line and avoiding the space problem:

```
$ declare -a case=("060610" "080813" "101016" "121219" "141422")

$ printf '%s\n' "${case[@]}" | sed 's/../& /g'
06 06 10
08 08 13
10 10 16
12 12 19
14 14 22
```

If you want it back into an array, you can use `mapfile`